# Internet slow on new computer when connecting through router

Tags: router, internet

I have a new Windows 10 computer and find that the internet is very slow on it when connected to our router. I've connected to our Netgear N300 router using both a wireless USB dongle and using the ethernet cable. Both are quite slow. I don't have this speed problem with any of the other devices in the home when they connect to the router (phones, laptop, etc). The new computer doesn't have speed problem when I use my phone as a wireless hotspot either, so it isn't entirely just a problem with the computer. There must be something going on with both the router and computer that doesn't make them very compatible. Any suggestions or is just time for a new router?

Comment: Try an external wifi adapter to see whether the problem is the computer or its network adapter.

Comment: I don't think the Question as written has enough information to speculate on a root cause or a solution. It would be nice to know the details of the Wi-Fi client hardware (the router isn't the only Wi-Fi hardware that matters; the client Wi-Fi hardware specifications matter too). It would also be nice to have some quantified performance test numbers for both the wireless and wired cases, and similar cases but with a different device that gets the normal speeds you've come to expect. Right now all we have is a  subjective/anecdotal "very slow"/"quite slow", which isn't much to work with.

Comment: That said, an N300-class router is likely limited to the crowded 2.4GHz band, and it's tech from 2006, so it's quite old. Modern client devices are usually AC1200-class or better, so you would do well to upgrade to an AC1200-class or better wireless router *with gigabit Ethernet ports* (that last bit is important). You can get a TP-Link Archer A6 or C6 for about US$45. That should tide you over until a year from now when you can jump up to Wi-Fi 6E (most people are probably best off skipping Wi-Fi 6 and waiting for 6E).